# MS-Access run time error 3073 when doing Insert

Tags: vba, ms-access

Here's my scenario. I have an Access 2010 database split into a Front End and a Back End, with VBA code for processing my data. Up until last week, I had no issues when I did my monthly mass inserts. The inserts are done by reading csv files as Excel spreadsheets and inserting the data into the Access tables (not all of the data will be inserted, so each line must be processed separately). When I ran Friday, I all of a sudden started getting random 3073 errors (Operation must use an updateable query). It can happen on any table in the database.

I reran using debug and set break points in my error handler, and discovered if I move from the break point back to the query execute command and step through it, I don't get the error. Here is a sample insert:

```
INSERT INTO OtherMeasures (HapId, SurveyTypeId, Score, Comments) 
    VALUES (86792, 9, 21.00, '').
```

Here the VBA code that  creates the SQL:

```
Private Sub storeOthType(ByVal hapId As Long, ByVal othType As String, _
                    ByVal othScore As Integer, ByVal othComment As String, _
                    ByRef db As DAO.Database)
  Dim sql As String
  On Error GoTo foundError

  Dim typeId As Integer
  typeId = lookupId(othType, "Description", "DataTypes", False, db)

  sql = "INSERT INTO OtherMeasures (HapId, SurveyTypeId, Score, " + _
           Comments) " + _
           "VALUES (" + CStr(hapId) + ", " + CStr(typeId) + ", " + _
                        Format(othScore, "##0.00") + ", '" + _
                        Replace(othComment, "'", "''") + "')"
  db.Execute sql, dbFailOnError
  Exit Sub
foundError:
  MsgBox "Error in storeOthType: " + CStr(Err.Number) + ", " + _
       Err.description + ". SQL: " + sql + "."
  logError "Error in storeOthType: " + CStr(Err.Number) + ", " + _
       Err.description + ". SQL: " + sql + "."
End Sub 'storeOthType
```

Anyone have an idea on what's causing this? We're planning on moving the back end to SQL Server, which I suspect will solve this problem, but until that happens, it would be nice if I was able to resolve this...

Comment: Please show more code... i.e.all code related to this insert. Are you using 'CurrentDB', etc.

Comment: Yes, way up in the main sub, I have "Set db = CurrentDb".

Comment: Unrelated, but IMO the comment on `End Sub 'storeOthType` should be killed with fire.

Comment: Why? It makes it very easy to determine where the end is when scrolling fast with many subs/functions.

Comment: *Proper* indentation does that too. And doesn't need to be maintained when you refactor/rename the procedure. Oh, and you don't need to stop and read the comment when you scroll *fast* either.

Comment: Also, if your procedures are long enough that you need a comment at the end to remind you what is ending, they're too long.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious, so this may be one of those 'ugh, why me' situations. First guess is 'something' changed somewhere - but at least you have a clue of when. Is this a multi-user, or just you? Split Db? I would Compact & Repair (FE & BE). Sometimes you don't have the luxury of taking weeks to find the cause, so you may want to consider a workaround (open recordset, .AddNew, etc. or possibly just trap the error, pause a second, retry insert).

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn I was advised to split the DB so that we could make it multi-user, but all that has done is given the users phantom "exclusive table locked" errors (I say phantom because if I went into the backend from their accounts, I had no problem). I suspect this is one of the Access-isms that will disappear when I get it into SQL server. I have done the C&E, but won't know if that affects anything until I get this month's data in April... My thought was to do the trap / retry, but I figured just in case someone had come across this... Thanks.

Comment: replace all +'s with &

Comment: @Mat'sMug It is properly indented. The commenting is a style that has served me well over the years. I don't see where it hurts anything or the removal solves anything.

Comment: Hey, it's your code, not mine - FWIW the VBE's indent size is 4 spaces and yours seems to be 2, which contributes to make the code feel more crowded than it really is. End-of-scope comments **in any language** are a terrible idea and get removed in any decent peer review, just sayin'.

Comment: @Comintern I had a young coworker tell me there's no excuse for a method to be larger than a screen until he realized I am feeding dozens of args into legacy systems that the client has no intent to replace as long as they work. When you're handling that amount of data, breaking into "bite sized" code to fit a smaller size doesn't accomplish anything. In a perfect world, they would rewrite all their systems and use databases done in the proper normal form. Unfortunately, I don't have that option with them.

Comment: @Mat'sMug, I copied pasted from my properly indented code, but only indented enough so that it would display as code here.

Answer (score 1):

It could be the use of '' for an empty string where the table expects *Null*.

You may find this function handy to avoid exactly that:

```
' Converts a value of any type to its string representation.
' The function can be concatenated into an SQL expression as is
' without any delimiters or leading/trailing white-space.
'
' Examples:
'   SQL = "Select * From TableTest Where [Amount]>" & CSql(12.5) & "And [DueDate]<" & CSql(Date) & ""
'   SQL -> Select * From TableTest Where [Amount]> 12.5 And [DueDate]< #2016/01/30 00:00:00#
'
'   SQL = "Insert Into TableTest ( [Street] ) Values (" & CSql(" ") & ")"
'   SQL -> Insert Into TableTest ( [Street] ) Values ( Null )
'
' Trims text variables for leading/trailing Space and secures single quotes.
' Replaces zero length strings with Null.
' Formats date/time variables as safe string expressions.
' Uses Str to format decimal values to string expressions.
' Returns Null for values that cannot be expressed with a string expression.
'
' 2016-01-30. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function CSql( _
    ByVal Value As Variant) _
    As String

    Const vbLongLong    As Integer = 20
    Const SqlNull       As String = " Null"

    Dim Sql             As String
    Dim LongLong        As Integer

    #If Win32 Then
        LongLong = vbLongLong
    #End If
    #If Win64 Then
        LongLong = VBA.vbLongLong
    #End If

    Select Case VarType(Value)
        Case vbEmpty            '    0  Empty (uninitialized).
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbNull             '    1  Null (no valid data).
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbInteger          '    2  Integer.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbLong             '    3  Long integer.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbSingle           '    4  Single-precision floating-point number.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbDouble           '    5  Double-precision floating-point number.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbCurrency         '    6  Currency.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbDate             '    7  Date.
            Sql = Format(Value, " \#yyyy\/mm\/dd hh\:nn\:ss\#")
        Case vbString           '    8  String.
            Sql = Replace(Trim(Value), "'", "''")
            If Sql = "" Then
                Sql = SqlNull
            Else
                Sql = " '" & Sql & "'"
            End If
        Case vbObject           '    9  Object.
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbError            '   10  Error.
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbBoolean          '   11  Boolean.
            Sql = Str(Abs(Value))
        Case vbVariant          '   12  Variant (used only with arrays of variants).
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbDataObject       '   13  A data access object.
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbDecimal          '   14  Decimal.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbByte             '   17  Byte.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case LongLong           '   20  LongLong integer (Valid on 64-bit platforms only).
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbUserDefinedType  '   36  Variants that contain user-defined types.
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbArray            ' 8192  Array.
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case Else               '       Should not happen.
            Sql = SqlNull
    End Select

    CSql = Sql & " "

End Function
```

Please study the in-line comments for typical usage.

Comment: No, that wouldn't be it. I only allow null values for dates. All other columns default to a value appropriate for their type.