# Add Error "3134" Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement - Update and Delete error '3061' Too few parameters

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have limited experience with Access. I followed some YouTube tutorials and made a functioning DB a couple of months ago.

I adapted the first DB, which essentially is changing the field names in the table in the Access file.

I can't get the new DB to function. I have a form with a subtable of the main table and it has a few text fields to fill in with the information to input. Then it has a few buttons to the side that either Add to the table, Delete from the table, Clear the text fields, Close the form, Edit a selected field, and then the Add button changes to Update after you Edit a field so that you can click Update to update the selected field after you've made changes to it.

All of this works in my first DB and in theory it should work exactly the same after changing the field names in the new DB and the corresponding txt field names and so on. I am having a tough time getting it to work for Add, Update, or Delete.

The error on the Add is Run time error "3134" Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

The Update and Delete error is run time error '3061' Too few parameters. expected 1.

The Clear works, as well as the Close and Edit.

Here is the code:

```vb
Option Compare Database

Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    'when we click on button Add there are two options
    '1. for insert
    '2. for update
    If Me.txtICN.Tag & "" = "" Then
        'this is for insert new
        'add data to table
        CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblInventory(ICN, manu, modelNum, serialNum, descr, dateRec, projectNum, dispo, flgDispo, dateRemoved, comments)" & _
        " VALUES(" & Me.txtICN & ", '" & Me.txtManu & "', '" & Me.txtModel & "', '" & Me.txtSerial & "', '" & Me.txtDescrip & "', '" & Me.txtDateRec & "', '" & Me.txtProjectNum & "', '" & Me.txtDispo & "', '" & Me.chkFlag & "', '" & Me.txtDateRemoved & "', '" & Me.txtComments & "')"
    Else
        'otherwise (Tag of txtICN store the Lab Inventory Control Number to be modified)
        CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblInventory " & _
        " SET ICN = " & Me.txtICN & _
        ", manu = '" & Me.txtManu & "'" & _
        ", modelNum = '" & Me.txtModel & "'" & _
        ", serialNum = '" & Me.txtSerial & "'" & _
        ", descr = '" & Me.txtDescrip & "'" & _
        ", dateRec = '" & Me.txtDateRec & "'" & _
        ", projectNum = '" & Me.txtProjectNum & "'" & _
        ", dispo = '" & Me.txtDispo & "'" & _
        ", flgDispo = '" & Me.chkFlag & "'" & _
        ", dateRemoved = '" & Me.txtDateRemoved & "'" & _
        ", comments = '" & Me.txtComments & "'" & _
        " WHERE ICN = " & Me.txtICN.Tag
    End If

    'clear form
    cmdClear_Click
    'refresh data in list on form
    tblInventorySub.Form.Requery
End Sub

Private Sub cmdClear_Click()
    Me.txtICN = ""
    Me.txtManu = ""
    Me.txtModel = ""
    Me.txtSerial = ""
    Me.txtDescrip = ""
    Me.txtDateRec = ""
    Me.txtProjectNum = ""
    Me.txtDispo = ""
    Me.chkFlag = ""
    Me.txtDateRemoved = ""
    Me.txtComments = ""

    'focus on ICN text box
    Me.txtICN.SetFocus
    'set button edit to enable
    Me.cmdEdit.Enabled = True
    'change caption of button add to Add
    Me.cmdAdd.Caption = "Add"
    'clear tag on txtICN for reset new
    Me.txtICN.Tag = ""
End Sub

Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
    DoCmd.Close
End Sub

Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()
    'delete record
    'check existing selected record
    If Not (Me.tblInventorySub.Form.Recordset.EOF And Me.tblInventorySub.Form.Recordset.BOF) Then
        'confirm delete
        If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this inventory entry?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
            'delete now
            CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM tblInventory " & _
                "WHERE ICN = " & Me.tblInventorySub.Form.Recordset.Fields("ICN")
            'refresh data in list
            Me.tblInventorySub.Form.Requery
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub cmdEdit_Click()
    'check whether there exists data in list
    If Not (Me.tblInventorySub.Form.Recordset.EOF And Me.tblInventorySub.Form.Recordset.BOF) Then
        'get data to text box control
        With Me.tblInventorySub.Form.Recordset
            Me.txtICN = .Fields("ICN")
            Me.txtManu = .Fields("manu")
            Me.txtModel = .Fields("modelNum")
            Me.txtSerial = .Fields("serialNum")
            Me.txtDescrip = .Fields("descr")
            Me.txtDateRec = .Fields("dateRec")
            Me.txtProjectNum = .Fields("projectNum")
            Me.txtDispo = .Fields("dispo")
            Me.chkFlag = .Fields("flgDispo")
            Me.txtDateRemoved = .Fields("dateRemoved")
            Me.txtComments = .Fields("comments")
            'store ICN in Tag of txtICN in case id is modified
            Me.txtICN.Tag = .Fields("ICN")
            'change caption of button add to Update
            Me.cmdAdd.Caption = "Update"
            'disable button edit
            Me.cmdEdit.Enabled = False
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: So... what was the exact error message?

Comment: And what line is highlighted when you click debug? Or, which line throws the error when you step through the code using F8?

Comment: did you change the names of the objects in your forms?

Comment: Sorry, the error I'm getting on the Add button is Run time error "3134" Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. The Update and Delete error is run time error '3061' Too few parameters. expected 1.

Comment: Are you getting *query* syntax error, or a VBA syntax error?  FWIW you should be parameterizing your queries - to borrow a phrase from chat, it "looks like you're building an SQL injection engine".

Comment: The errors I'm getting are from VBA itself.

Comment: "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement" isn't a VBA error - it's just raised as a VBA error. VBA syntax errors will be at compile-time, not run-time.  Just put some breakpoints in there and check to see what the SQL you're attempting to execute is.

Comment: What happens when the user has a `'` character in one of the text boxes?

Answer (score 0):

What data types are dateRec, flgDispo, dateRemoved? Values for DateTime fields must be delimited with # not '. Is flgDispo a Yes/No type? If so, this is numeric type field and number values do not have delimiters.

Why delete records? Do you really want to lose history? Why not just flag as 'Archived' or 'Inactive'? Deleting records should be a rare event.

I always give subform containers a name different from the object they hold, like ctrInventory:
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM tblInventory WHERE ICN = " & Me.ctrInventory!ICN

Answer (score 0):

First, all your date expressions must be formatted like this:

```
", dateRec = #" & Format(Me.txtDateRec.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#" & _
```

or you could apply my CSql function to handle all this:

[Convert a value of any type to its string representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42630902/ms-access-run-time-error-3073-when-doing-insert/42633280#42633280)

However, it appears that you could make life much easier for yourself by simply *binding* your form to the table - and then remove all of this code as the form will handle edit, insert, and delete automatically.